# AG-Grid - How to insert a line break into my cell data

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-ng2

I'm new to AG-Grid, so forgive me if this is a dumb question. We're using the OSS version of Ag-Grid in an Angular 5 application. I have a column where I am combining two sets of summary data and showing them. I would like to have a line-break between the two pieces of text.

Right now it's doing this:

"Summary One Summary Two"

I want it to do this:

"Summary One
Summary Two"

So far I've tried and HTML break tag, \r\n and just \n and nothing has worked. Is this possible to do?

Thanks,
James

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use `cellRenderer` to achieve this.

Have a look at below `colDef`.

```
{
  headerName: "Custom column", 
  cellRenderer: function(param){
    return param.data.col1 + '<br/>' + param.data.col2;
  }
}
```

You might need to set `rowHeight` in `gridOptions` as well.

Live example: [Plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/zJxGN1?p=preview)

Comment: the perfect answer I was looking for

Comment: can this be solved without using cell Renderer

Comment: You can use
`wrapText: true,
autoHeight: true`
as columnDefs options for auto size

Comment: Before using in newer versions (in 2022+), look at AG Grid's allowance for HTML in cellRenderer.

Answer (score 7):

I have an even simpler solution without cell renderer. By the way I am using the ag-theme-balham theme. Simply set the cellStyle to white-space pre and you are able to use \n to insert a new line.

```
columnDefs()
...
   valueGetter: ({ data }) => 'first value\nsecond value',
   cellStyle: { 'white-space': 'pre' }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use below:
cellStyle: { whiteSpace: 'pre' }

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).